# Can we access the data of setter and getter from other method of same class? #JAVA

Tags: java

**

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("********WELCOME TO CUSTOMER DETAIL**********");
    System.out.println("");
    BankAccount customerDetails = new BankAccount();
    customerDetails.setAccountNumber(527553054);
    System.out.println("Account Number : " + customerDetails.getAccountNumber());
    customerDetails.setBalance(300000.00);
    System.out.println("Balance : " + customerDetails.getBalance());
    customerDetails.setCustomerName("Anish Shrestha");
    System.out.println("Customer Name : " + customerDetails.getCustomerName());
    customerDetails.setEmail("blah@gmail.com");
    System.out.println("Email : " + customerDetails.getEmail());
    customerDetails.setPhoneNumber(980709277);
    System.out.println("Phone Number : "+ customerDetails.getPhoneNumber());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("*********************");

    BankAccount deposit = new BankAccount();
    deposit.depositFunds(566);
}
```

}

package learnJava;

public class BankAccount {

```
  public void depositFunds(double depositAmount) {
        this.balance += depositAmount;
        System.out.println("The total sum of money : " + this.balance);
  }


private long accountNumber ;
private double balance;
private String customerName;
private String email;
private long phoneNumber;

//SETTER
public void setAccountNumber(long accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance; 
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email ;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(long phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber ;
}

//GETTER
public long getAccountNumber() {
    return this.accountNumber;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
    return this.customerName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}
public long getPhoneNumber() {
    return this.phoneNumber;
}
```

}

**

i could not add up deposit Amount to main balance
Is it due to the setter/getter or there is something wrong in my code......
I am beginner  so help me out guysss.....

I am not able to access the data of getter
What could be the problem or is it a rule?

Comment: What do you mean 'accessing the data of setter'? setters don't return values.

Comment: Share your class code and the code that fails

Comment: Oh sorry i meant getter

Comment: without seeing your code, we can only speculate there's a problem in it

Comment: Here comes the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copy-paste your code, there is no problem. In comment, the output :

```
      BankAccount deposit = new BankAccount(); 
      deposit.depositFunds(100); // The total sum of money : 100.0
      deposit.depositFunds(100); // The total sum of money : 200.0

      System.out.println(deposit.getBalance()); // 200.0
```

Comment: I wanted to add the previous balance too ?
Cant i add this  balance  "customerDetails.setBalance(300000.00);" ??

Comment: So if I understand, you need to display old balance and new balance.

Comment: You could add a field `balanceHistory` of type list. You can add to the list the new balance every time you use setBalance and depositFunds.